# How to filter Arraycollection with selected tree node

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, flash-builder

I have a window with a tree (each node is a category).
I have a dataprovider what contains picture url and category.

My goal is to filter the view with only selected node. Several nodes may be selected in the time.

I don't find how to do that. Can you help me.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is plenty of documentation available on how to filter collection classes in Flex.  Collections are the most common dataProvider's in Flex Apps.

Here is one [sample](http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_Using_the_to_ArrayCollection_s_filterFunction-5441.html).

Read through the [formal docs here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf668d2-7ff2.html).

Comment: thanks for that but my question is about filter arraycollection an not about sort.